# Can we enable user to control local notifications?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

can we enable user to select weather he want local notifications as in sound, badge. or not.

Thanx alot in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to implement this yourself as some settings component of your own application.